# Core audio.h not found in my project?

Tags: iphone, ios, frameworks

I have added the CoreAudio framework using the link binary with libraries. However, when I compile it says "CoreAudio/CoreAudio.h" not found. Please help me

Comment: How are you writing the import statement?

Comment: #import <CoreAudio/CoreAudio.h>

Comment: Clean your project, restart Xcode, rebuild, etc

Comment: when I see the headers folder of the imported Core audio framework ,it does'nt have any file named coreaudio.h.It has only one file called coreaudiotypes.h

Comment: where are you using this in your project ?

Comment: If that's true then you have deleted it somehow and you will need to reinstall Xcode.

Comment: how can I download coreaudio.h from the internet?

Comment: @borrrden:no in my case also if has only coreaudiotypes.h

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try adding

```
#import<CoreAudio/CoreAudioTypes.h>
```

Comment: But the .mm file which I downloaded contained # import<CoreAudio/CoreAudio.h> Will it still work if I change this import file to the one you are saying?

Comment: If you have added the CoreAudio framework, This will work. Hopefully :). I suggest you give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

Actually in iOS only CoreAudioTypes.h header is available under CoreAudio.framwork

In OSx addition to this ,you can have AudioDriverPlugin.h, AudioHardware.h, AudioHardwarePlugin.h, CoreAudio.h and HostTime.h as a extra header file . I am not sure what is you requirement . But have look at this [link.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/CoreAudioFrameworks/CoreAudioFrameworks.html)